# Install openCV in Raspberry pi 3 fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, conda

when I try to install OpenCV in RAspberry Pi 3 B+, it gives me following error:

```
$pip install opencv-python

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: 
none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I have tried other ways also:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
pip3 install opencv-python
python3.6 -m pip install opencv-python
```

All give the same above error!

I tried few other ways:

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

Still cant import cv2

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I tried menpo channel

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

Please help. What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCv currently works on Raspbian 9-Stretch. 
Update os system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

2) Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
```

3) Install Python 3 and Pip3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

4) Install Opencv:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

5) Extra depencies for Opencv and the Camera:

```
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
```

Voila! OpenCv2 is installed.